# Spring tool suite Pivotal tc server startup: web apps not loaded

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I'm creating a Hello World application in STS 3.9 on Windows using the legacy Spring MVC Template. I've created an MVC project, start the server and everything is fine on my home computer. I see this logged from the console:

```
Aug 02, 2017 9:56:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2161 ms
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Aug 02 21:56:10 PDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
```

...

And the home page for the app is there. The problem is on my work computer. I do the same setup, but the Pivotal server is not loading the web app. There is no error. But instead of the above console output I get:

```
Aug 07, 2017 8:36:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 662 ms
Aug 07, 2017 8:36:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 389 ms
```

That's it. No error, and no indication that the ContextLoader is doing anything. The server home page appears fine, but the application home is not there (I get a 404 error when visiting the page). There is nothing in the Error Log. I have done a clean on the server and redeployed this many times with multiple versions of STS. I compared the two environments and everything seems in place - the Hello World app is there under wtpwebapps. Looks like everything was deployed correctly with servlet-context and root-context files in place. But on startup the server is not recognizing that there is an app. I can't see what is different between the two environments. I have deleted and re-installed STS, created many different tc servers, etc.

What would be preventing the server from finding and loading this webapp?

thanks,

andrew

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why this was happening but I fixed it by deleting my Maven repository: C:\Users[username].m2, then going to to STS, right-clicking on my project and selecting Maven --> Update Project, and checking the "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases" box before clicking OK. Then the ContextLoader started working at server startup.